# how to isolate JNA bindings that are platform specific?

Tags: java, windows, macos, jna, multiplatform

I have a project where I defined a JNA wrapper to Windows kernel32 library, upon which I have made several helpers that are not critical for the project but increase the integration to the platform (namely: system debug logging with `OutputDebugString` + DebugView and **Mailslot** messaging features).

Here is my JNA defines:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIFunctionMapper;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APITypeMapper;

public interface JnaKernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    //StdCall is needed for lib kernel32

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map ASCII_OPTIONS = new HashMap(){
        {
            put(OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, W32APITypeMapper.ASCII);
            put(OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, W32APIFunctionMapper.ASCII);
        }
    };
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map UNICODE_OPTIONS = new HashMap(){
        {
            put(OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
            put(OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
        }
    };

    Map DEFAULT_OPTIONS = Boolean.getBoolean("w32.ascii") ? ASCII_OPTIONS : UNICODE_OPTIONS;

    JnaKernel32 INSTANCE = (JnaKernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", JnaKernel32.class, DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    //some system defines
    //...

}
```

And the Mailslot definition:

```
public class Mailslot {

    static JnaKernel32 kernel32 = JnaKernel32.INSTANCE;
    boolean localMailslot = false;
    int lastError = 0;

    private int hMailslot = JnaKernel32.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    //...
}
```

And in some places I have also

```
static JnaKernel32 kernel32 = JnaKernel32.INSTANCE; //to call OutputDebugString
//...
kernel32.OutputDebugString("some debug message");
```

My concern is that project *could* be used also on GNU/Linux or MacOS X but obviously the `Native.loadLibrary` fails at runtime if executed on e.g. OSX.

I am considering about

- either porting the native feature with other JNA binding
- or simply disable the existing Windows kernel32 binding when running on another platform as it is just convenient but not mandatory helpers.

How can I isolate the platform-specific features and calls that are made? I was thinking about moving the JNA part to a runtime loaded plugin perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is really a general software development strategy.

1. **Identify the API that your client code needs**

   In this case, it might be `MailsSlot.sendMessage(int destID, String msg)`
2. **Abstract the implementation details behind that API**

   `public interface MailSlot {
       void sendMessage(int destId, String msg);
   }`
3. **Provide one or more concrete implementations to meet the API contract**

   `public class Win32MailSlot implements MailSlot {
       public void sendMessage(int destId, String msg) {
           // Do stuff here that's windows-specific
       }
   }`

   `public class OSXMailSlot implements MailSlot {
       public void sendMessage(int destId, String msg) {
           // Do stuff here that's windows-specific
       }
   }`

   Choose the appropriate implementation at runtime:

   `MailSlot mslot = Platform.IS_WINDOWS ? new Win32MailSlot() : new OSXMailSlot();`

After a few implementations, you may find some duplicated code, which you might then refactor into an abstract base class shared among the platform-specific implementations.

See the JNA platform [`FileUtils`](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/FileUtils.java) class for an example of such an strategy.